# Raspbian Jessie LUKS Encryption?

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I have been trying to use luksOpen to open an encrypted partition in Raspbian Jesse. It would seem that there is no kernel support for any of the ciphers. This is ridiculous as Wheezy had it built in meaning that it was likely purposely removed. Anyone know how I can re-add the cipher support in the kernel, start the modules and then continue with my encrypted partition?

Answer (score 2):

I had no problem using luksOpen on 2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.zip and 2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie-lite.zip. Perhaps you just need to recreate your initramfs after running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` with `sudo -E CRYPTSETUP=y mkinitramfs -o /boot/initramfs.gz`?

I wrote a guide on how to implement LUKS on a Raspbian root partition at https://robpol86.com/master/raspberry_pi_luks.html and the kernel had no problem when running `cryptsetup -y --cipher aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 --key-size 256 luksFormat /dev/mmcblk0p2`.